# Pig STORE to MySQL database- ClassNotFoundException: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-pig

I'm working with Pig and I'm trying to store my results in a MySQL database. Based on help that I've found on this site, I'm using:

```
STORE final_data INTO '$dbTable' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$db','$dbUser','$dbPass','INSERT INTO $dbTable');
```

I'm also importing the jars (the directories are correct):
piggybank.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar

However, I am getting the following error when I run my Pig script:

```
[MainThread] ERROR org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage - can't
load DB driver:com.mysql.djbc.Driver

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


[MainThread] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2999:
Unexpected internal error. could not instantiate
'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage' with arguments
'[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, jdbc:mysql://x.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/database,
username, password, INSERT INTO myTable]'
```

Does anyone see an error with the code? Or, maybe I'm missing a jar? If you have another recommendation for how I can store Pig data in a MySQL database I'd love to hear about that too.

Comment: Try to add mysql-connector-java to the `PIG_CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to add mysql-connector-java to the PIG_CLASSPATH

Thanks, this was exactly what I needed to do! Doing REGISTER isn't enough apparently.

Comment: But after adding to the classpath i'm still getting the same error
`ERROR org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage - can't
load DB driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`